# Creating 2 independent animations using core animation

Tags: ios, core-animation

Lets say I have a animation that is going for 10 seconds that I've already committed, but then  for some reason I decide within that 10second I want to add a new animation, is that possible or would the first animation block the 2nd one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible :) Just commit the animations at the same time or declare a new one then commit the animation, it will run under a different thread. If there are some issues with older iOS versions that I don't know about just put the animation components in separate sub-views and initiate them separately :)